# timestamp with timezone в prepared-запросе PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, timestamp, timezone, preparedstatement

Таблица в PostgreSQL БД:

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
link VARCHAR(128),
title VARCHAR(128),
summary VARCHAR(2048),
content VARCHAR(16384),
published TIMESTAMPTZ
```

Вставка записи (Python, py-postgresql):

```
insert = _database.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO SchemaName.TableName (link, title, summary, content, published) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)"
)
…
insert(link, title, summary, content, published.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')) # published — datetime, остальное — str
```

Выполнение вызывает ошибку:

```
could not pack parameter $5::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE for transfer
…
LOCATION: CLIENT
DETAIL: '2018-11-08 01:38:31 -0500'
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Интересно, а если просто передавать `published`, то драйвер сделает преобразование объекта питона в объект базы?

Comment: @gil9red, да, должен сделать. Если в базе тип данных “with timezone” то должно правильно отработать

Comment: Да, точно сделал. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно передавать объект [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) как есть, драйвер сам разберется с преобразованием объекта в тип базы:

```
...
insert(link, title, summary, content, published)
```